# Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net problem in Production on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, log4net

I am building ASP.NET Core MVC Application using Net Core 3.1 and I am trying to use log4net with package
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore.

In my Program.cs I have log4net configuration in Main method:

```cs
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging(builder =>
                {
                    builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
                    builder.AddLog4Net();
                }).Build();

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                try
                {
                     ...
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
                }

                // Log some things
                logger.LogInformation("Hello logging world!");
                logger.LogError("Error!");
                logger.LogWarning("Warn!");
            }

            host.Run();
        }
```

On Windows it is working like charm - it will create *logs* folder under my project and log files, but in production machine on linux - ubuntu 18.04, no *logs* folder and no logs :(

Edit: My log4net configuration looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender" >
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
    <file value="logs/" />
    <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd.'txt'"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="100"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="15MB"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Please show configuration of Log4Net.

Comment: @Hostel Hi, I have included my log4net config.

Comment: @mayo589 - any resolution to this? Having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue: put the whole path in the file value configuration, for example:

```xml
<file value="/var/www/your-web-site/logs/" />
```

in your case:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender" >
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
    <file value="/var/www/your-web-site/logs/" />
    <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd.'txt'"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="100"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="15MB"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
    </root>
</log4net>
```

And then ensure that ASP.NET Core service has permissions on that folder!